# ASP NET como apuntar a una carpeta que está fuera de mi proyecto

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Hola amigos tengo un proyecto en donde guardo imagenes en una ruta de mi ordenador, guardo el **path** en una tabla de sql, pero cuando trato de renderizar mi imagen en un `<img src="miruta"/>` pues no llega, entonces. La ruta en donde yo estoy guardando es la siguiente.

> C:\Users\yo\source\repos\WebFiles\Creditos\File

mi proyecto se encuentra en la siguiente ruta

> C:\Users\yo\source\repos\WebProyect\

entonces lo que imprime mi render es esto

```
<img src="C:/Users/yo/source/repos/WebFiles/Creditos/_621669732_19_09_2019image-40-devices1.png" />
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: ¿No te falta el directorio "File" en el path?: <img src="C:/Users/yo/source/repos/WebFiles/Creditos/"File"/_621669732_19_09_2019image-40-devices1.png" />

Comment: Antes de seguir preguntando , revisa todas las preguntas que tienes, varias han sido respondidas y me late que muchas de ellas han solucionado tu problema, acéptalas de ser ese el caso, ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) :D

Answer (score 0):

No puedes asignar una absoluta a un `img` porque el usuario que entre a tu pagina no va a tener la imagen en la ruta `C:/Users/yo/source/repos/WebFiles/Creditos/_621669732_19_09_2019image-40-devices1.png`.

Si quieres mostrar una imagen que esta fuera del directorio del proyecto, tendras que retornar los bytes del archivo desde un action.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class RecursosController : Controller
{
  public FileResult ObtenerImagen()
  {
     string rutaAbsoluta  = ObtenerRutaAbsolutaImagen(); // metodo que buscaria la ruta absoluta de la imagen que deseas mostrar

     return File(rutaAbsoluta,"image/png");
  }
}
```

Entonces en la etiqueta:

```
<img src="~/recursos/obtenerimagen" />
```

Comment: lo que quiero es guardar esa imagen en un directorio para que desde otro proyecto le pasé la ruta y en mi otro proyecto pueda buscar esta misma imagen

Comment: Y por que no has explicado esto mismo en tu pregunta principal?, si no va a ser muy difícil darte una solución.

Answer (score 0):

Estas en un proyecto web, no puedes usar una ruta fisica a un archivo para visualizarlo en un tag de `img` tienes que usar una `url` ya sea absoluta o relativa

```
<img src="WebFiles/Creditos/_621669732_19_09_2019image-40-devices1.png" />
```

esto lo que hara seria buscar en el website que ejecuta siendo `http://sitio:puerto/...`

si la imagen esta en una carpeta fuera entonces deberias exponer un intermediario, por lo general un handler o un aspx que recibe en el querystring el nombre de la imagen y la escribe en el response

[Downloading Files In ASP.NET Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/downloading-files-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp/)

entonces con el handler podrias usar

```
<img src="download.ashx?filename=_621669732_19_09_2019image-40-devices1.png" />
```

la idea es que el handler tome el nombre del archivo, obtenga la ruta fisica y envie el byte array como respuesta en el response para que el tag img veas la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Considera utilizar el siguiente código en la clase program:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = "D:\\" 
});
```

Esto añade d:\ al proyecto. puedes usar ese webrootpath para indicarle ha que directorios quieres tener acceso.

También puedes usar:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("D:\\") // Añadimos el directorio D:\ para servir archivos estaticos.
});
```

más info: [statics files asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Echa un vistazo quizas te sirva.